# Issue with transfer NFT

Tags: solana-program, cnft

i hope someone can help, im actually following: https://www.helius.dev/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-compression-on-solana#transferring-cnfts

But im having issue: (im using  "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum": "^3.1.2")

1. Cannot find name 'createTransferInstruction'.

Is there any quickway to transfer?

Answer (score 2):

createTransferInstruction() can be found in the "@solana/spl-token" package

Comment: i think the one in "@solana/spl-token" is different from what was originally in @metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum ? can you confirm?